# Firestore Transaction in "each loop" or loop in transaction

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have loop which adds data to Firestore database using transaction.

```
jQuery.each(objIN, function (key, value) {
    var product = products.doc(key);
    db.runTransaction(function (transaction) {
        return transaction.get(product).then(function (doc) {
            ...
            ...
            transaction.update(product, {
                productQTY: newProductQTY,
                [warehouseIN]: newSelectedWarehouseQTY

            });

        });

    }).then(function (newProductQTY) {
        console.log("New product qty ", newProductQTY);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // This will be an "population is too big" error.
        console.error(err);
    });
})
```

Is it OK to do this way or it is better to put loops inside transaction.
What is the best option to update firestore in bulk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two bulk update statements that Firestore supports (transaction and batch) exist to help ensure data consistency across multiple documents. There are no performance gains from using a bulk update. In fact, if there is no requirement for cross-document consistency in an update, it is often faster to run separate small updates, as there is the opportunity to parallelize those updates (in the client-side code).

So: yes, what you're doing is fine. :)